# How to add pagination for div content in angular2

Tags: angular, pagination

How to add pagination for div content in angular2, and div with p tag.I am displaying log list as paragraph.So I want to add pagination for every 10 lines p tag.

Here is my html file code:

```
<div id="default_log" class="col-md-12" *ngIf="hidediv" >
   <div id="top-padding">{{servername}} &nbsp; &nbsp; {{logType}} &nbsp; 
   &nbsp; <a id="close" class="closeButton" (click)="onclick()"></a></div>
      <div id="stuff">
         <p *ngFor="let defaultLogItem of defaultLogItems">
         {{defaultLogItem.logList}}</p>
         </div>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use http://michaelbromley.github.io/ng2-pagination/#/ for pagination.

Usage:

```
<element *ngFor="let item of collection | paginate: { id: 'foo',
                                                      itemsPerPage: pageSize,
                                                      currentPage: p,
                                                      totalItems: total }">...</element>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I could find is using an external library to handle this kind of task, [NG2 Pagination](https://github.com/michaelbromley/ng2-pagination) seem to handle this task in an easy and complete way.

Just check the documentation to know how to easily implement it.

Comment: Thank you your responses...I have followed this link:http://plnkr.co/edit/JVQMPvV8z2brCIzdG3N4?p=preview
But here problem is i do not have config.js file or systemjs.config.js file as i am using webstorm IDE. So how to add config.js file code for my issue.

Comment: Is your project based on Angular-CLI? The IDE you are using does not affect the project.

Comment: Yes i am using Angular-CLI only. and IDE is webstorm. Can you please suggest me what is wrong in that. I am not getting you clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ngx-pagination` as `ng2-pagination` is deprecated. Please go through following link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pagination

Just add `npm install ngx-pagination --save library` in your angular application.

```
*ngFor="let item of collection | paginate: { id: 'foo',
                                                  itemsPerPage: pageSize,
                                                  currentPage: p,
                                                  totalItems: total }">
```

`itemsPerPage`, `currentPage`, `totalItems` are inbuilt tags. You just need to pass values accordingly. Better to use lazy loading at the backend as per page request and items per page request.